# Items empty after doing db bind

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuefire

So I am trying to display basic data in a list using vuefire and vue, but the items object is empty
 this is the list items.vue file

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>List Item</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Item Price</th>
          <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr v-for="item of items" :key="item['.key']">
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.surname }}</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { db } from '../config/db';

export default {
  components: {
      name: 'ListItem'
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  firebase: {
    items: db.ref('drivers')
  },
  }
}
</script>
```

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: ""
};
so this is my db.js file 
let app = Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const db = app.database()
```

The list items seem to be empty and no data is displayed, i believe it might have to do with the db.ref(drivers) but i am using an insert function and that works, the DB has 5 entries already

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the plugin? (`firestorePlugin` in case of firestore)

```
import { rtdbPlugin } from 'vuefire';

Vue.use(rtdbPlugin);
```

Also, is `drivers` a collection? It should be `db.collection('drivers')` then.